# How to perform the default logic of a SvelteKit Form Action inside a custom use:enhance SubmitFunction?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I ask the user for confirmation before performing a SvelteKit Form Action. I have a custom submit function which performs the default action logic in case the confirm `returns` true:

```js
const submit: SubmitFunction = async ({ cancel }) => {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this post?")) {
    return async ({ update }) => {
      return update();
    };
  } else {
    cancel();
  }
};
```

The code above *works*, but I also tried the following:

```js
const submit: SubmitFunction = async ({ cancel }) => {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this post?")) {
    return async ({ result }) => {
      return await applyAction(result);
    };
  } else {
    cancel();
  }
};
```

And it seems like it does the same thing. Are there any differences between the two snippets in terms of behaviour? Is one recommended over the other for a technical reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differences listed in the docs are:

- `applyAction` does not [invalidate all data](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-invalidateall).
  `update` also has an `invalidateAll` option to change the behavior, though.
- `applyAction` on `success` or `failure` sets `$page.status` to `result.status` and updates `form` and `$page.form` to `result.data` regardless of where you are submitting from.
  `update` does not do this for actions of other routes.

So generally, you can just use `update` unless you want to prevent invalidation or want to update `status`/`form` with data from a "foreign" action.

Comment: Thanks! So I should return `update` without awaiting it?

Comment: `update` returns a promise without value, it should just be awaited. `enhance` does not expect the submit function to return anything.

Comment: I didn't know that 'The submit function does not do anything with the return value, so no need to return anything'. Thanks for the info.